# Why my form submits on a 'back' button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form which consist of 7 input fields displayed individually with 'next-button' to show next input and hide current and 'back-button' to hide current and show previous. The problem is that the submit function on the last input runs when I click 'back-button' and it saves incompleted fields in the database. I don't know why and how to prevent it. Here is a sample code of 'back-button' :

```js
Template.submitProblem.events({
  'click .back1':function() {
    //show/hide items with removeClass()/addClass()
    $('#submit-why1').addClass('hidden');
    $('#submit-problem').removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

and the submit function on the last input field :

```js
Template.submitProblem.events({
  'submit form':function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var problem = $(event.target).find('[name=problem]').val();
    var why1 = $(event.target).find('[name=why1]').val();
    var why2 = $(event.target).find('[name=why2]').val();
    var why3 = $(event.target).find('[name=why3]').val();
    var why4 = $(event.target).find('[name=why4]').val();
    var why5 = $(event.target).find('[name=why5]').val();
    var solution = $(event.target).find('[name=solution]').val();

   Problems.insert({
      problem: problem,
      why1: why1,
      why2: why2,
      why3: why3,
      why4: why4,
      why5: why5,
      solution: solution,
      submitdate: new Date()
    });

    Router.go('submitted');
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="submitProblem">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main-page">
      <form class="form text-center">
        <div id="submit-problem">
          <input autofocus="autofocus" type="text" name="problem" id="problem" placeholder="What's the problem ?"/>
          <input type="button" id="route" value="Find Its Route" class="route btn btn-sample">
        </div>

        <div id="submit-why1" class="hidden">
          <input autofocus="autofocus" type="text" name="why1" id="why1" placeholder="This problem exists, because..."/>
          <input type="button" value="Answer" class="btn-success btn answer1">
          <div>
          <button class="btn back1 back-btn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-3x"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        ...
```

Comment: I removed your code from the snippets feature since there is nothing to run without any HTML.

Comment: I also don't understand why you tagged the question with CSS.  Please do not tag-spam on this site.  Thanks.

Comment: Please show your html

Comment: you use _button_ tag for your back button, and: [submit is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always specify the type attribute for the `<button>` element because different browsers may use different default types for the `<button>` element. In your case, you need to update your back button to have a type button so it doesn't submit.

```
<button type="button" class="btn back1 back-btn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-3x"></i></button>
```